# Need to get max date value from another table to order by product list

Tags: linq

I have two tables.

First table is product table as below:

```
Product
Id    Name
1     Apple
2     Desktop
3     Laptop

ProductStatus
Id   ProductId LatestUpdatedDate
1      2       01-01-2021
2      2       08-07-2021
```

I am expecting the below result:

```
2 Desktop
1 Apple
3 laptop
```

How to make this query into linq?

Sample that i try

```
var query= _ProductRepository.Table;

 var productStatusHistory = (from psh in _productStatusHistoryRepository.Table
                                            group psh by psh.ProductId into g
                                            select g.OrderByDescending(t => t.CreatedOnUtc).FirstOrDefault());

                query = (from q in query
                         join ps in productStatusHistory on q.Id equals ps.ProductId into l_ps
                         from ps in l_ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         let index = ps == null ? default(DateTime) : ps.CreatedOnUtc
                         orderby index
                         select q);
```

This query working fine. I want to make this as single query

Comment: You can simply make left join and then order by date and then select Product value

Comment: The sample data isn't really descriptive of what you're trying to achieve. You've only added two status entries for _one_ of the products.

Comment: Secondly, how are you fetching the data? SQL query? ORM? If ORM, have navigation properties been defined?

Comment: @Flater I have added the sample code that i try. My sample code only return one row but i need all products

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi I have added sample code. Please check

Comment: What is the `query` and  what is `productStatusHistory`? I cannot figure out what is queried.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv  query is the product list